# Can't get GCBV with context to show books by author unless i set the pk value as fixed

Tags: django, django-views

Using a Generic Class Based View and a Book model with a FK (author), I can only return all books or books of fixed value id.

Using the python shell, I can retrieve the value I need, e.g.

```
b.all().filter(author=6)
>>> <QuerySet [<Book: bookA>, <Book: bookB]>
```

However, I can't seem to translate this via a GCBV using context. Below, on the query below, how do I tell it to filter (for whatever the author id value of this page is? I.e. substitute the fixed value for the dynamic one.

Views.py

```
class AuthorDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.DetailView):

      context_object_name = 'author'
      queryset = Author.objects.all()

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # call the base implementation first to get a context
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # add Queryset of All books
        context['book_list'] = Book.objects.filter(author=4)
        return context
```

Each author page should show all related books. All examples i've seen don't use the id, name instead. Or it's a function based view. I'm fine using FBV if that's the only way, but i'd like to know how to use it in both, so I started with the GCBV.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't do this at all. You use the reverse relation in the template:

```
 {% for book in author.book_set.all %}
```

Comment: Are you saying for the View, to remove all of the context code and only use model=author, and then add the template code to the template?